# Percent from a list

Tags: python, list, function, lambda, percentage

I have a List with points from a Test

```
points= [0,0,0,0,0,0,8,8,8,9,10,11,11,12,12,13,14,14,15,15,16,
 16,17,17, 18, 19,21,21,23, 23, 24, 24, 24, 25,25, 25,
 26, 27, 27, 28, 29, 29, 29, 29, 30, 30, 30, 31,31, 32,
 34, 35, 36, 36, 37, 38]
```

If we assum all participants get full points on the next two tests(in total 80, 40 for each test), which percentage of participants can still attain the mark “A”. The function shall return the percentage, in the mathematical sense so between 0 and 1.
You can get an A if you have more than 88 points.

Thats my code till now and I dunno what to do next

[image]

The answer should look likes this:

Potential Top Marks: 89.285714%

Comment: Please, post the code as actual text and not as a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple solution without numpy:

```
sum(  i +80 >= 88 for i in points  )/len(points)*100
```

This returns (in Python 3):

```
89.28571428571429
```

edit: simplified by h4z3s tip.

Comment: this returns 0. Python 2

Comment: he is not using python 2 though

Comment: as you can see from his print.

Comment: `1 for i in points if i +80 >= 88` can be simplified to `i+80 >= 88 for i in points` because booleans are ints and `True==1` ;)

Comment: Thank u guys for your help!

Answer (score -1):

### Use this:

**Without `numpy:`**

```
potential = [p + 80 for p in points]
percentage = sum([1 for i in potential if i>=88]) / float(len(potential)) * 100
89.28571428571429
```

**Using `numpy`:**

```
import numpy as np

potential = [p + 80 for p in points]
percentage = sum(np.array(potential)>=88) / float(len(potential)) * 100
89.28571428571429
```

Comment: great! if my answer helped consider upvoting and accepting it so that other can also benefit from it